# RxJS: How to do some clean-up before the next valid value is passed?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have to streams which I merge to get an URL to load an image: one stream for drop events and one for an file input change. On every new path I load this image and draw it to a canvas. This canvas is passed into another stream. It looks like this:

```
// prevent browsers default behavior for dropTargetElement
[ 'drop', 'dragover' ].forEach(function(eventName) {
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dropTargetElement, eventName).subscribe(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

// file path stream merged from openFileInputs change and openFileDropTargets drop
Rx.Observable.merge(Rx.Observable.fromEvent(inputElement, 'change').map(function(event) {
  return event.target.value;
}), Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dropTargetElement, 'drop').map(function(event) {
  return event.dataTransfer.files[0].path;
})).map(function(path) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = path;

  // note: I return an Observable in this map function
  // is this even good practice? if yes, is mergeAll the best
  // way to get the "load" event?
  return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(image, 'load');
}).mergeAll().map(function(event) {
  return event.path[0];
}).subscribe(function(image) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  canvasState.onNext(canvas);
});
```

(Side question: Is it "allowed" to return Observables in `map`?)

My `canvasState` looks like this:

```
var canvasState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);

// draw image
canvasState.filter(function(canvas) {
  return !!canvas;
}).subscribe(function drawImage(canvas) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

As you can see I append the canvas to the body, if my canvas value is truthy. But every time a new canvas comes in I would like to remove the old one. What is the best way to achieve that? Is something like this possible?

```
// draw image
canvasState.filter(function(canvas) {
  return !!canvas;
}).beforeNext(function(oldCanvas) {
  // remove old one
}).subscribe(function drawImage(canvas) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Comment: Note that you probably need to listen to the image's error event as well so you can take action if an image fails to load...

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Interesting question with a good answer. Note that there are other resources you create and don't clean up: the event listener themselves. I just wrote about this in https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1016
Found this question while searching how to clean up these subscriptions... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Nested Observables

Yes it is normal to have a `map` operation return an Observable.  This gives you an observable stream of observable streams.  There are Rx 3 operations to flatten that nested observable one level:

- mergeAll - subscribe to all of the inner streams as they arrive.  You usually end up concurrently subscribed to multiple streams and usually your final stream will have results from the different inner streams intermingled.  You can supply a `maxConcurrent` parameter to limit the number of concurrent inner subscriptions.  When the limit is hit, new inner observables get queued and do not get subscribed until a previous inner observable completes.
- concatAll - subscribe to each inner observable stream one at a time, in order.  Your resulting stream will produce items in a predictable order.  Concat is just `Merge` with maxConcurrent set to 1.
- switch - subscribe to the first inner stream.  Then, when a new stream arrives, "switch" to it.  Basically unsubscribe from the previous inner stream and subscribe to the latest inner stream.  Use `switch` when you only want to listen to the most recent inner stream.

(In my code, I've also implemented a fourth flattening operator: `concatLatest` which is like `concat`, but when an inner stream completes, instead of jumping to the next stream in the queue, it jumps straight to the most recent sequence in the queue, throwing away any inner streams skipped.  It is sort of in between `concat` and `switch` in behavior and I find it very useful for handling backpressure while still producing results).

So, it is very common to have `.map(...).mergeAll()` or `.map(...).concatAll()` or `.map(...).switch()`.  It is so common, that there are Rx methods for these 3 cases:

- `source.flatMap(selector)` is equivalent to `source.map(selector).mergeAll()`
- `source.concatMap(selector)` is equivalent to `source.map(selector).concatAll()`
- `source.flatMapLatest(selector)` is equivalent to `source.map(selector).switch()`

### Your Code

With the above information, I'd suggest you use `switch` instead of `merge`.  As your code stands now, if someone changes the value quickly, you could have 2 image requests out simultaneously and if they complete in the wrong order you will end up with the wrong final canvas.  `switch` will cancel the stale image request and switch over to the new one.

Note that if the user keeps changing the value faster than the image requests can complete, then they could never see any images since you'll keep switching to the new one.  This is where I usually use my `concatLatest` instead because it will complete some intermediate requests now and then while it is attemping to keep up.  YMMV.

### Cleaning up the old canvases

When my observable stream has a map operation that produces resources that must be cleaned up, I tend to use `scan` because it can track the previous value for me (without me needing to go make a closure variable to hold the previous value):

```
canvasState
    .filter(function (c) { return !!c; })
    .scan({}, function (acc, canvas) {
        return { previous: acc.canvas, canvas: canvas };
    })
    .subscribe(function (v) {
        // remove the old canvas
        if (v.previous) { document.body.removeChild(v.previous); }

        // add the new one
        document.body.appendChild(v.canvas);
    });
```

Comment: This is a great and nicely explained answer which helps to clean-up my code tremendously and helps me to understand RxJS. Everything worked flawlessly. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Aww, that `scan` to get the previous value is nice!

Comment: concatLatest() sounds like the missing operator I've always wanted, any chance you could share the implementation, please?